# How can I make my AngularJS/bootstrap modal take up the full screen?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, fullscreen

We are developing an AngularJS application in which we have a modal that we open like this:

```
$modal.open({
    templateUrl: 'template/modal/calcMeasurementConfig.html',
    controller: 'app.calcMeasurementConfig',
    keyboard: false,
    windowClass: 'xxl',
    backdrop: 'static',
    resolve: {
        ...
    }
});
```

We are using bootstrap classes to determine the size of the modal. As you can see from the code snippet above, I am setting the modal size with `windowClass: 'xxl'`. I would like to increase the size to take up the whole screen (or close to it). But xxl seems to be the largest size.

I tried to override it by creating my own class like this:

```
.fullscreen {
   width: 100vw !important;
   min-width: 100vw !important;
}
```

and setting `windowClass: 'fullscreen'`, and indeed I see the fullscreen class when I inspect the modal in the dev tools:

[image]

...but the modal is smaller than it was before.

Is there a way to make the modal take up the full screen size? Thanks!